# Communicating with a serial port in a bit bang state

Tags: c++, serial-port, rs485

My question is largely a clarification question, I am trying to communicate through a serial port in a bit bang sort of sense. Whereas I want to output out of the serial port exactly what I write to it..

If I write 0-0-0-1, I would want the output on the wire to be 0-0-0-1.

The reason I ask this question is because it seems like using the DCB object to configure the port, I have to set all sorts of settings like Stop Bits and Parity?

Is there a way to configure this port as 'raw' as possible? I don't want anything being sent that I don't send.. if that makes sense..

```
    //Open the serial port
    hComm = CreateFile( "\\\\.\\COM1",                 // Name of the Port to be Opened
                    GENERIC_WRITE,                     // Write Access
                    0,                                 // No Sharing, ports cant be shared
                    NULL,                              // No Security
                    OPEN_EXISTING,                     // Open existing port only
                    0,                                 // Non Overlapped I/O
                    NULL);                             // Null for Comm Devices

DCB dcbSerialParams = { 0 };    // Initializing DCB structure
    dcbSerialParams.DCBlength = sizeof(dcbSerialParams);

    //retreives  the current settings
    Status = GetCommState(hComm, &dcbSerialParams);    
    if(!Status){
        //Error in GetCommState!
    }

    dcbSerialParams.BaudRate = 10000;      // Setting BaudRate = 10000
    dcbSerialParams.ByteSize = 8;             // Setting ByteSize = 8
    dcbSerialParams.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT;    // Setting StopBits = 1
    dcbSerialParams.Parity   = ODDPARITY;
```

Comment: Simple: it's impossible :) The serial protocol requires at least one start bit and one stop bit. Use the parallel port if you want to play with transmission as GPIO

Comment: @Equod could the transmission be very large?

Comment: What do you mean by "very large"? It depends on your application. Anyway, consider that using bit-banging it's not a best practice (for many reasons). If you think you need it, probably it's something wrong with the system design.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't quite sure from the question article what you were having problems with.

Are you worried about the bit order of the MSB/LSB or the endianness of 4-byte integers? Or will data be added or deleted or changed by operating as a terminal?

Please add the exact content.

---

Bit order is a hardware standard specification issue so you don't have to worry about it.

The endian problem seems to be lacking in your understanding.
Serial port communication is basically byte-by-byte communication.
You need to set the data in a byte array and send it, and the received data is a byte array.
It is a problem on the application program side to give them meanings such as 4-byte integers and single/double precision floating point numbers.

Then, looking at your source code, it seems that you are calling the Windows Win32 API directly.
[Communications Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/devio/communications-functions)
The Win32 API and device drivers only have raw mode.
Unlike Unix `tty` devices, it doesn't have any features like character completion/conversion/newline waiting buffering or control code equivalents. (Unless you explicitly specify XON / XOFF flow control)
On Windows, those features aren't APIs, but libraries/framworks that run on them.

Basically, each setting such as DCB and timeout must be done according to the specifications of the device with which you are communicating. Even if you say "all settings", the number of items will fit on one page.
[DCB structure (winbase.h)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/ns-winbase-dcb)